# How can I mount a partition on every reboot using Bash Script?

Tags: scripts, filesystem, partitioning

I have a partition mounted with `mount /mnt/filesys.bin /mnt/mymnt/`

Each time I reboot, I need to remount. How can I keep this mounted after every reboot?

Comment: Hello. Isn't it possible to add entry in `/etc/fstab` for that?

Comment: Can you explain more? I am new to Linux

Comment: I think `/etc/fstab` is the correct think to look for, not a Bash script.

Comment: How is there not a command that just saves my currently mounted drives? Is this a toy OS?

Comment: Well, there **is** such a command. `sudo cp  /etc/mtab /etc/fstab` would do that. It's not something I would ever want to try! At any given time, I have a number of temporary mounts that I wouldn't _want_ saved.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From [`man fstab`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/fstab.5.html):

> The file `/etc/fstab` contains descriptive information about the filesystems the system can mount. `fstab` is only read by programs, and not written; it is the duty of the system administrator to properly create and maintain this file.

To do what you want you just need to add an entry for this mount in `/etc/fstab` as follows:

1. Open new terminal window <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
2. Open the file `/etc/fstab` for edit with root privileges, using `nano`:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/fstab
   ```
3. Go to the bottom of the file and add the following line - here I'm assuming it is an image file, so we need to use the `loop` option ([reference](https://itekblog.com/mount-iso-using-fstab/)):

   ```
   /mnt/filesys.bin /mnt/mymnt/ auto nofail,defaults,loop 0 0
   ```

   If you want to mount *physical* device (or partition), you can identify it by several different ways, for example by its UUID. To find the UUID use `sudo blkid` while the device is mounted (or use the GUI tool `Disks`). In this case the entry could look like:

   ```
   /dev/disk/by-uuid/a58b40e4-eb9b-4720-835b-785a3be3ae33 /mnt/mymnt/ auto nosuid,nodev,nofail 0 0
   ```

   or:

   ```
   UUID=a58b40e4-eb9b-4720-835b-785a3be3ae33 /mnt/mymnt/ auto nosuid,nodev,nofail 0 0
   ```

   Where `a58b40e4-eb9b-4720-835b-785a3be3ae33` is the UUID of your device.
4. Save the file: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, then exit from `nano`: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.
5. Restart the system or type `sudo mount -a` to see the result.

Do not forgot to remove that entry if you remove the image file.

Comment: For external media I use UUID and the 'nofail' option. To get the UUID, issue the ````blkid```` command in terminal, while the device is mounted,then to fstab use ````UUID=<uuid> /mnt/mymount auto nofail,defaults````

Comment: If I was writing the answer now I would include some example of [`systemd.mount`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.mount.html) unit.

Answer (score 5):

@pa4080 is totally right, but the really easy solution is (running as the superuser, so `sudo su` first):

```
mount /mnt/filesys.bin /mnt/mymnt/
grep mymnt /etc/mtab >>/etc/fstab
```

The first line mounts your device with whatever other options you need, the second will put it into `/etc/fstab` with the same options so that it gets mounted on every reboot.

Comment: You're the only person with a solution that's an actual command, on the command line. Everyone else has an essay about how to manually modify the files by hand.